# Handling a problem in Unity making my game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm handling a problem in Unity and I don't know how to fix it. I have a scene where you select your car. I have particles for smoke, when hp is under 50, explosion, when gets hit by another car or when you fall down. But for some reason when I pick the blue car all particles are playing when they're not supposed too. Also when you hit a car (the enemy) the car is supposed to explode and be removed but nothing happens. Also for some reason, when you hit an obstacle, for example a crate, your supposed to lose -2 HP but it doesn't work in the other cars only in the first one. At first, they were all working fine but after a format in my pc, those problems appeared. Here is the code which has HP and When you hit an obstacle or enemy.

```
public class PlayerControl : MonoBehaviour
{
private float speed = 20.0f;
private float turnSpeed = 30.0f;
private float horizontalInput;
private bool Won = false;
private bool gameover = false;

    public int Health = 100;
    
    public ParticleSystem Smoke;
    public ParticleSystem Dust;
    public ParticleSystem Dust2;
    public ParticleSystem Explosion;
    
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Health <= 50)
        {
            Smoke.Play();
        }
    
        if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name == "Car Select")
        {
            return;
        }
        
    }
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Target"))
        {
            Won = true;
        }
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Barrier"))
        {
           
            Health -= 3;
            
        }
        else if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Rock"))
        {
            Health -= 7;
    
        }
        else if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Crate"))
        {
            Health -= 1;
    
        }
        else if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Cone"))
        {
            Health -= 4;
    
        }
        else if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Spool"))
        {
            Health -= 3;
    
        }
        else if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Barrel"))
        {
            Health -= 2;
    
        }
        else if(other.gameObject.CompareTag("Mega Rock"))
        {
            Health -= 50;
    
        }
        else if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("DeadLine"))
        {
            gameover = true;
            Instantiate(Explosion, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            Explosion.Play();
            Destroy(gameObject);
    
        }
        else if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy"))
        {
            gameover = true;
            Instantiate(Explosion, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        NoSpeed();
        if (Health <= 0)
        {
            gameover = true;
            speed = 0;
            turnSpeed = 0;
            Health = 0;
        }
        if (Health <= 49)
        {
            speed = 10.0f;
        }
        if (Won == false || gameover == false)
        {
            Explosion.Stop();
    
            horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
            //Moves the car forwards
            transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed);
            //Rotate the car so it can turn Right or Left to Horizontal Axis
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, Time.deltaTime * turnSpeed * horizontalInput);
        }
        if (Health <= 50)
        {
            Smoke.Play();
        }
        if (Health <= 50 || Won == true || gameover == true)
        {
            Dust.Stop();
            Dust2.Stop();
        }
        if(Won == true)
        {
            Won = true;
            speed = 0;
            turnSpeed = 0;
        }
    }
    void NoSpeed()
    {
        if(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name == "Car Select")
        {
            speed = 0f;
            turnSpeed = 0f;
        }
    }
```

Well I checked the code but nothing is wrong. ChatGPT also checked it and said there's nothing wrong in the code. Also tried to wrote:

`private void Start() { Smoke.Stop(); Explosion.Stop();}`

But didn't work.

Comment: tbh there isnt really enough information - but as "dust" never gets played, im going to assume you have them play on start.. so they are always playing unless health is < 50.  Smoke then plays at < 50, the explosion if you hit the trigger deadline. so, you need to debug whats going on if this is not what you wanted.

Comment: Actually dust particle is supposed to play when you start the game so that works fine. What i want is when your HP gets under 50, dust stop and smoke play and then when you hit a car or the trigger deadline to play the explosion particle but the problem is they all start  at the beggining. But most confusing is that the first car in the Car Select scene is that when you sleect it and play all particles plays and when you hit the objects you lose hp.Instead with the others explosion is not played and they don't lose HP for some reason they dont get deleted at deadline.

Comment: then you probably either didnt check health is 100, or you have play on start.

Comment: I already played on start and still the same. Also wdym to check if Health is 100? Could you give me an example?

Comment: You never reset the Health. Try introducing a proper state machine for your game loop. And don't start particle systems on every tick like you do with your Smoke in the `FixedUpdate`.

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time im new in unity. I haven't set a button to restart the game yet. I will debug it and tell you. But also i can't send a video to show you excatly what i mean

Comment: I debut it and nothing happend... Also what i did now is: In the void Update() what i wrote and kinda worked(not for the first car when i select in the scence Car Select for some reason) is: `void Update() { if(Health == 100) { Smoke.Pause(); }  }`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.